# What does it mean f(const double) in the parameter of function?

Tags: c++

I have function with that f parameter. What does it mean?

```
static double Test(double cx, double f(const double), const double dx)
{
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a function pointer. Does this code help: https://wandbox.org/permlink/gxlwFEIPwiOxPusg

Comment: @jabaa: Does parameter adjustment turn function types into function pointer types when processing the argument list of a function declaration?  I know array types get adjusted, and I know there's an implicit conversion on values, but I didn't think it was legal to write a function type as shorthand for a function pointer type.  IOW, I think that parameter should be written `double (*f)(const double)`

Comment: Ahh, I found [the rule in `[dcl.fct]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5) and it does indeed do adjustment of parameters whose type is a function type, and has been that way at least since C++03.

Comment: typedef double DP;
DP brent(const DP ax, const DP bx, const DP cx, DP f(const DP), const DP tol, DP& xmin)
{
 const int ITMAX = 100;
 const DP CGOLD = 0.3819660;
 const DP ZEPS = std::numeric_limits<DP>::epsilon() * 1.0e-3;
 int iter;
 DP a, b, d = 0.0, etemp, fu, fv, fw, fx;
 DP p, q, r, tol1, tol2, u, v, w, x, xm;
 DP e = 0.0;

blablabla..

Comment: Please do not add code in comments, it's completely unreadable. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Assuming the `const` is throwing you off, the `const` is not part of the signature.